# Finding Expiring Leave of employee in each month based on validity period in master table

Tags: sql

TableA contains a list of Employees, their allowed leaves in month, and validity of leave.

TableB contains Leave taken by each Employee in each month.

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS #TableA

CREATE TABLE #TableA(
    [EmployeeID] [nvarchar](10) NULL,
    [AllowedLeaveinMonth] [int] NULL,
    [ValidForNumberofMonths] [int] NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]

INSERT INTO #TableA (EmployeeID, AllowedLeaveinMonth, ValidForNumberofMonths) VALUES
(N'E0001', 1, 4),
(N'E0002', 1, 3),
(N'E0003', 1, 3)
```

- 

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS #TableB
CREATE TABLE #TableB(
    [EmployeeID] [nvarchar](10) NULL,
    [Months] [date] NULL,
    [LeaveTaken_in_Month] [int] NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]


INSERT INTO #TableB([EmployeeID], [Months], [LeaveTaken_in_Month]) VALUES (N'E0001', '2023-08-01', 0);
INSERT INTO #TableB([EmployeeID], [Months], [LeaveTaken_in_Month]) VALUES (N'E0002', '2023-10-01', 1);
INSERT INTO #TableB([EmployeeID], [Months], [LeaveTaken_in_Month]) VALUES (N'E0003', '2023-10-01', 1);
INSERT INTO #TableB([EmployeeID], [Months], [LeaveTaken_in_Month]) VALUES (N'E0001', '2023-09-01', 1);
INSERT INTO #TableB([EmployeeID], [Months], [LeaveTaken_in_Month]) VALUES (N'E0002', '2023-09-01', 0);
INSERT INTO #TableB([EmployeeID], [Months], [LeaveTaken_in_Month]) VALUES (N'E0003', '2023-09-01', 2);
INSERT INTO #TableB([EmployeeID], [Months], [LeaveTaken_in_Month]) VALUES (N'E0001', '2023-10-01', 0);
INSERT INTO #TableB([EmployeeID], [Months], [LeaveTaken_in_Month]) VALUES (N'E0002', '2023-10-01', 1);
INSERT INTO #TableB([EmployeeID], [Months], [LeaveTaken_in_Month]) VALUES (N'E0003', '2023-10-01', 1);
INSERT INTO #TableB([EmployeeID], [Months], [LeaveTaken_in_Month]) VALUES (N'E0001', '2023-11-01', 1);
```

Lets say E0001 gets 1 leave each month, and if he does not take that leave it will be carried forward to next month. For E0001 Leave Earned in August can be used in August, September, October, November. As per his master table, After 4 months,  August leave will expire in December if not used.

For E0002 unused leave will expire in November because master table says 3 months validity and so on.

I need output as follow.

| EmpID | Month | PrevAccumLeaves | AllowedLeaves | LeavesTaken | ExpLeaves | LeavesLeft |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| E0001 | 2023-08 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 1 |
| E0001 | 2023-09 | 1 | 1 | -1 | 0 | 1 |
| E0001 | 2023-10 | 1 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 2 |
| E0001 | 2023-11 | 2 | 1 | -1 | 0 | 2 |
| E0001 | 2023-12 | 2 | 1 | -1 | -1 | 1 |

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution.

```
SELECT
    n.EmployeeID,
    n.Months,
    ISNULL(
        SUM(n.AllowedLeaveinMonth - n.LeaveTaken_in_Month - n.LeaveExp) OVER (
            PARTITION BY n.EmployeeID
            ORDER BY n.Months
            ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND 1 PRECEDING
        ),
        0
    ) AS OpeningBalance,
    n.AllowedLeaveinMonth,
    n.LeaveTaken_in_Month,
    n.LeaveExp,
    n.AllowedLeaveinMonth - n.LeaveTaken_in_Month - n.LeaveExp + 
    ISNULL(
        SUM(n.AllowedLeaveinMonth - n.LeaveTaken_in_Month - n.LeaveExp) OVER (
            PARTITION BY n.EmployeeID
            ORDER BY n.Months
            ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND 1 PRECEDING
        ),
        0
    ) AS ClosingBalance
FROM (
    SELECT 
        tb.EmployeeID,
        tb.Months,
        ta.AllowedLeaveinMonth,
        tb.LeaveTaken_in_Month,
        ISNULL(e.LeaveExp,0) AS LeaveExp
    FROM #TableB tb
    LEFT JOIN (
        SELECT 
            b.EmployeeID,
            b.Months,
            a.AllowedLeaveinMonth,
            b.LeaveTaken_in_Month,
            CASE WHEN (a.AllowedLeaveinMonth-b.LeaveTaken_in_Month < 0) THEN 0 ELSE a.AllowedLeaveinMonth-b.LeaveTaken_in_Month END AS LeaveExp,
            DATEADD(month, a.ValidForNumberofMonths - 1, b.Months) AS ExpiryDate
        FROM #TableB b
        JOIN #TableA a ON b.EmployeeID = a.EmployeeID
    ) AS e ON tb.EmployeeID = e.EmployeeID AND tb.Months = e.ExpiryDate
    LEFT JOIN #TableA ta ON tb.EmployeeID = ta.EmployeeID
) AS n
ORDER BY n.EmployeeID, n.Months;
```